# Find the unique rows in a file with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take rows which are uniques. Here unique means cells should not share any letter.
I have an excel file like this with thousands of rows:

| id | letters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B,G |
| 2 | B,G |
| 21 | C,D |
| 30 | E |
| 35 | K,M |
| 40 | E,F |

The values in letters column should not be contained in another letter cell.
The output should be like this, because the letters C,D,K and M don't appeared in another cell:

| id | letters |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | C,D |
| 35 | K,M |

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, you need to try to solve your problem yourself. If you run into trouble, bring us your non-working code and we can help you understand what's going wrong. You've tagged this question with [tag:python] and [tag:dataframe], do you already have Python code reading your file into a Pandas dataframe? Even that would be a great start on the larger problem. Right now, it's not clear if you know anything about Python or dataframes, so it's hard to give an useful answer using them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split values by `,`, explode for possible remove all duplicates and join per groups to original joined values, last get rows with same data:

```
s = (df['letters'].str.split(',')
                  .explode()
                  .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
                  .groupby(level=0)
                  .agg(','.join))

df = df[df['letters'].eq(s)]
print (df)
   id letters
2  21     C,D
4  35     K,M
```

Comment: Very elegant answer! At first, I thought about checking each row by iterating through all the "letters" column over all rows. But your method is much shorter